# Could an alien learn human history from a time lapse of Earth?

Tags: space, aliens, earth

If some alien or other organism placed a camera of some kind on the Moon’s surface and pointed it at Earth, and recorded video through all of human history, starting at the first evolution of Homo sapiens, what could the alien learn about humans by watching this video (assuming it only captures video without any other kind of information)? What signs of civilization would be the most obvious? Would the alien see Earth change from global warming or environmental collapse? If humanity had a huge nuclear war in the semi-near future, would this be visible from space?

Comment: When you say video...... Do you just mean light visible to humans or a wider (or narrower or different) spectrum?

Comment: Critical requirement:  What's the resolution of the camera?

Comment: Even a fairly low-res camera will note the rise of industrial civilization due to the light produced by cities.  It would also note a fall in the lack of said light.

Comment: @A Rogue Ant I’d prefer human spectrum, though if there’s some stuff in other wavelengths that could be cool too. Depends entirely on what is available to show.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel High resolution, I think? Enough to see the Earth’s surface clearly. One image I was hoping for was if the camera would catch the explosions at Hiroshima and Nagasaki in WWII, clearly enough to see exactly where they hit in Japan. I’m not even sure how visible a nuke would be from space, though.

Comment: "High resolution" might be a meaningful term when dealing with video on our computers, but when we are talking about an alien camera on the moon it ceases to have a meaningful definition.  Are we talking 20 megapixels or a terapixel?  And what frame rate?  If you're going to see a nuke you need something pretty close to realtime, not timelapse.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel I’m not sure how to work out the exact resolution I would need lol but the frame rate would probably be 24-30 frames per second or so. The video can be in real time, but I’d assume it would be easier for viewing if a lot of it was sped up.

Answer (score 1):

**They could learn a lot about humans.**

As mentioned in the comments, a lot depends on the resolution. Detecting artificial light is one thing. Another might be [spectrographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectroscopy#Molecules) measurements, detecting man-made gases in the upper atmosphere. With sufficient resolution, other artifacts from dams to highways down to individual houses and even humans might be detected. (The last example would require a big camera. Recon sats can probably detect individual humans if they know where to look for them, but they're flying much lower than the moon.)

**But is that history?**

As generally understood, history doesn't just describe miles of railway or battleships steaming from *A* to *B*. The aliens would be unable to determine the causes for the effects they see. Even if they were able to note the [Thirty Years War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Years%27_War), by tracking armies and burning cities, would they understand that it was caused by a monk splitting the church a century before?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For my case I’d assume the camera doesn’t have spectrographics and while it has high resolution, it’s not high enough to see individual houses, etc. The smallest area it could view in high/usable resolution would probably be the size of Madagascar, so the viewer would be limited to major signs of civilization (artificial light from cities, deforestation, etc.) but I wanted to see what else I could play with.